# Dynamic Data Target on Modal PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am looping a dynamic PHP value and also a button that is linked with a modal form.

The problem is that im currently setting the data-target to one of the dynamic values being looped but it never gets to work.

This is the PHP+HTML code being looped:

```
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($seleccionar_requerimientos)){

                    $req_id = $row['req_id'];

                    ?>    

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo "{$req_id}" ?></td>

    <!-- Here we place the data-target to dynamic value -->    
    <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" **data-target="#<?php echo $req_id; ?>" ><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button></p></td>

    <!-- Here we set the dynamic ID linked to previous trigger -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $req_id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Editar Requerimiento</h4>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $req_desc_corta; ?>"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="fas fa-wrench"></span> Actualizar</button>
      </div>
        </div>
  </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Where am I wrong? I can see on the site source code that both values are currently properly set but modal still not showing.

If values on both data-target and ID are dynamic, they are properly displayed on site source code but the modal never triggers.

If values are manually writen, the modal pops up correctly which confirms modal code is working, however since its not a dynamic value it opens up the same form for every looped item, which is the reason to write a dynamic value on them.

This is the HTML output I get on the source code whiledisplaying dynamic values:

```
    <!-- Echo en bucle de los botones de editar el requerimiento -->    
    <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#9" ><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button></p></td>

    <!-- Pop Up con el form de editar el requerimiento -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="9" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Editar Requerimiento</h4>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="dsfgdfg"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
          <div class="modal-footer ">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" style="width: 100%;"><span class="fas fa-wrench"></span> Actualizar</button>
      </div>
        </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Weirdly, if I change

```
data-target="#<?php echo $req_id; ?>"
```

To

```
data-target="#9"
```

And I also change

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $req_id; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
```

To

```
<div class="modal fade" id="9" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
```

Then it works (with static values)

Comment: So on the source code, it's set correctly, so what's the issue then? I'm assuming the modal doesn't load? Have you tried loading other modals, do they work? Have you included the bootstrap javascript correctly?

Comment: Hello FrankerZ, thanks you so much for writing. The problem that is that it looks good on the source code but then it doesnt works when click.

If both data-target and id are dynamic values, they look good on the suorce code but they dont work. By the other side, if I manually write down a number on them then the modal works good (but not being dynamic, so every looped trigger opens up the same modal, which is the reason to show a dynamic value).

Comment: Being dynamic or static doesn't really change anything. If they're in the source code (You've checked both data-target and the actual modal id, and see the correct ID number implemented in both places, then you shouldn't have an issue). Edit your question, and post your output (The HTML source after this page renders).

Comment: @GuillermoFernándezRuiz do you work with several `$req_id`s? If yes, are you aware that you'are only assigning one of these at the time in your loop?

Comment: Thanks again FrankerZ, thats what I also think. I've writen down the HTML output on the main question

Comment: @MarcoDufal I am working with several $req_id s, however every modal trigger and modal form is being echoed with their respective $req_id s, so they are never duplicated

Comment: I think using only numbers for the `id` attribute is a bad idea. Please, can you use some better names and try again?

Comment: @emi Thanks you so much. I didnt knew about this. I'm now generating a random string for every loop and matching on both id and data target and works nicely now.

Thanks everyone also for helping!

Comment: Ok. Made the answer. Can you vote on it and mark as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using only numbers for the `id` attribute is a bad idea. Please, use some string before the number. From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp :

> Must contain at least one character

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your code is generating duplicate values for $req_id?
If the code works when you manually put the IDs in place then the problem is likely the Ids and there aren't many ways this could be wrong.  Either there are duplicate IDs or there's some other issue with the way they are being output.  Can you add the source code of the whole page?  Does you console warn you about duplicated IDs?